# Backup of Azure SQL Database to Recovery Services vault

Tags: sql, azure, backup

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to backup Azure SQL Databases (Not SQL on Azure VMs) to a service vault or a blob storage outside of the resource group the databases is located in. So far I have not found any resources on the topic. Can anyone confirm that this is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

The easiest way is that you could using **Export** to backup the database to blob storage outside of the resource group the databases is located in On portal.

For example:

**Export：**
[image]

Export database：
[image]

Choose the blob storage out of the resource group which the databases is located in:
[image]

For more details, please reference: [Export an Azure SQL database to a BACPAC file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-the-azure-portal).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This can only be done manually/scripted, though? We're looking for a solution that does backups on a regular basis.

Comment: @xltkx  On portal, you must do it manually. And  for your another question  that you want to backup on a regular basis,  there are also many ways can achieve it. Othera have asked the same question on Stack Overflow.  Reference this Azure blog: [How to automate Export Azure SQL DB to blob storage use Automation account](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/how-to-automate-export-azure-sql-db-to-blob-storage-use/ba-p/368864).

Comment: @xltkx In the end, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that confirmed my guesses! I have marked your answer as the answer!